# Are there any studies on how different sources of pornography effect someone?

Tags: sexuality

It is well-established that use of [pornography can cause sexual dysfunctions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5039517/).

Are there any studies that have evaluated the impact of pornography on an individual depending on the *type* of pornography used? Some examples of different types of pornography include erotica, adult audio, adult comics (Hentai), digital porn (3d figures or animation), adult games, adult videos etc.

(I am particularly interested to know whether they all have the same kind of impact or some are more detrimental to sexual and mental health than the other forms.)